# How to properly close android AVD in eclipse?

Tags: android

Sometimes I could launch AVD from snapshot, but sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't launch from snapshot I have  to start a AVD with "wipe user data" option. And it is taking like 5 minutes to start the new AVD. I think failed to launch AVD from snapshot is because I didn't properly close it. So is there a way?

---

still can't find a way to solve this snapshot problem "emulator: ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot has been saved for a different hardware configuration."
tried adb kill-server and adb start-server as C.d. said but not working. But restart by "wipe user data" is taking too long. Hlep!

Comment: Kill  the adb connection first, via adb kill-server and then adb start-server

Comment: just close it from top-right (in windows) corner, and that's it!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes adb gets confused just restart it with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` commands. Then check with `adb devices` command if the AVD is visible.

If android tools has not been added to your path variable you will need to go to the android SDK folder and run the command from the platform-tools directory.

Comment: where can I find or type adb kill-server and adb start-server in eclipse?

Comment: command console if the android tools are added path variable.  or go to android sdk's folder find platform tools directory via a command console then execute execute the command

Comment: for some reason I cannot type in console. I have Android as Display Selected Console. Sorry, just starts using eclipse.

Comment: I did not mean the eclipse console. Open a console in windows Start>type "cmd" press enter

Comment: So today my snapshot fails,and I opened the command prompt then went to the platform-tools directory and typed adb kill-server, then it only showed a newline, then I typed adb start-server it shows "* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *" ,after that I typped adb devices, it shows"* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *" and a newline. But after those steps I still cannot open avd from snapshot. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I guess there might be a problem with your adb but I cannot guess what kind of a problem. Maybe you can try re-installing the SDK if you desire.